# elasticsearch return empty list of objects to spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a problem with **Elasticsearch**.

I want to read data from **Elasticsearch** index with **Pyspark**. my data look like as below:

```
user_id: 123,
features: {
    hashtags: [
        {
            text: "hello",
            count: 2
        },
        {
            text: "world",
            count: 1
        }
    ]
}
...
```

and when data loaded it seems **Elasticsearch** return empty list of objects. my dataframe after read is look like as below:

```
+----------+-------------------+
|  features|            user_id|
+----------+-------------------+
|{[{}, {}]}|                123|
|    {[{}]}|                384|
|    {[{}]}|                 94|
|{[{}, {}]}|                880|
+----------+-------------------+
```

I read data from elastic with using this configuration:

```
tweets = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("es.nodes", "localhost") \
    .option("es.port", "9200") \
    .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "features.hashtags")\
    .option("es.read.field.include", "user_id, features.hashtags")\
    .option("es.resource", "twitter")\
    .load().limit(10)
```

can you help me for resolve it?